# What are the pros and cons of "super" access tokens with large numbers of scopes?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

**Context**

We use Identity Server for identity and access control in our solution. Our scope names have the form of URLs so they are 40-60 characters long.

Some time ago we received a request to increase the max length for scopes in the request. The default value is set to 300 in [InputLengthRestrictions](http://src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/Options/InputLengthRestrictions.cs) class and it can be changed very easily. However, after some discussions, it turned out that for now it may be enough to increase the max value to 500 or 1000 but in the future, an even bigger limit may be needed in order to be able to request 10, 20 or more scopes.

Here comes the question. Is it a good practice to request an access token with such a large number of scopes? What are the pros and cons?

**My thoughts**

From my perspective, the main benefit of having one "super" access token has one main advantage i.e. it is convenient because it allows you to call all APIs.

On the other hand, I see some drawbacks and/or code smells:

1. The fact that a large number of scopes must be requested may mean
   that scopes are too granular.
2. The fact that a large number of scopes must be requested may also suggest that scopes are used more as permissions. It is especially a problem in the case of long-lived tokens as they cannot be revoked easily.
3. Requesting a large number of scopes may suggest that you request
   more than you actually need. However, it is recommended to "choose the most restrictive scopes possible".
4. Having a super access tokens expose a higher security risk if such a token is intercepted.
5. In implicit flow, a token is passed in URL so the large super token can exceed the maximum length of the URL.
6. Super tokens might be too big to store them in cookies (it is a
   different topic if tokens should be stored in cookies).
7. Super tokens can be quite large so the network performance can be affected.

What do you think? Do you see any other pros/cons of super tokens? I'm not sure but maybe large super tokens can affect Identiy Server performance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have pros or cons for you, but perhaps this answer can help you.

Looking at IdentityServer you'll see three parts, the [resource, the client and the user](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html). IdentityServer has two main responsibilities, *authorize the client* and *authenticate the user*. User authorization is actually *not* the responsibility of IdentityServer. That's why they created [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

Consider the following resource:

```
resource = CalendarApi
    scope = Calendar.Read
    scope = Calendar.Write
    scope = Calendar.Event.Create
```

The resource is just a logical name. It can consist of one or seperate api's (as in projects), where an api can implement a single or multiple scopes. In the api a scope is an implementation of certain functionality.

Only a client can request a scope, because the client knows how to use the functionality.

Suppose I have two clients: Mvc1 and Mvc2. Mvc1 has a calender view and an admin page, while Mvc2 only shows the calendar.

My configuration:

- Mvc1: scope = Calendar.Read Calendar.Write Calendar.Event.Create
- Mvc2: scope = Calendar.Read

It has no use for Mvc2 to request all scopes, because it doesn't use the other functionality. It wouldn't make sense to request all scopes. And in case Mvc2 is a third party app, you shouldn't, because they could use it even when this was not the purpose.

Best practice here would be that a client only requests scopes that are allowed (as configured in IdentityServer) and may be implemented by the client.

So far the user was not involved, because there is no relation between scopes and users. However, the client needs the user (as resource owner) to actually access the resource.

It then comes to *user authorization* to determine whether the *user* can create events on the calendar. This 'permission' is not the scope.

The scope `Calendar.Event.Create` doesn't allow the *user* to create an event. It only allows the *client* to connect to the resource.

When combining the clients and users, then there is only one situation where a user can create an event: when a user with create permission uses the admin page in Mvc1.

Mvc2 can't access the resource, not even when the user has create permission.

Now getting to your question:

> Is it a good practice to request an access token with such a large
>   number of scopes?

The access token should only contain the scopes that are needed, as described above. Only necessary scopes should be requested by the client.

1. Agree. The number of scopes should not be too detailed. Don't treat scopes as permissions, e.g. create, edit, read. Though I did as example, a better scope would be `Calendar`, where the user permissions define what the user is allowed to do (CRUD permissions).
2. Agree, should be investigated.
3. I would say yes, as argumented above.
4. It is still the user that has to be authorized. But you should limit the possibility for clients to use functionality that was not meant for that client.
5. / 6. / 7. Hitting limits is a good indication that the architecture may need some redesign. In general you should not expose more than necessary and you should avoid hitting limits.

I suspect the problem is that scopes are used as permissions. Remove the 'CRUD' from the scopes and redesign user authorization. Don't set permissions in claims.

In my design there is no need for a super token, nor will I ever hit a limit. There are only few scopes, the access token only contains the sub claim and policy server tells me what the user is allowed to do.

I hope this helps you in any way. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I appreciate this detailed response; helped me see that I was myself conflating scopes and permissions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Service Account flow for same. Using it you can get token of respective client with all allowed scopes to client.

By this way your token does not have included all scope but has scope allowed to client.

I don't have sample code right now but you can check how service account can be implemented